# Application of logs

Tags: logarithms, applications

*The number of milligrams, $d$, of a drug remaining in a patient's bloodstream, $t$ hours after it has been administered, is given by the equation $d = 5(2.7^{.04t})$. To the nearest minute, how long will it take until only $2.5$ mg of the drug remains in the system?*

First, I set the equation equal to 2.5 and solved for $t$, where $t=1.7$. However, I am way off from my teacher's answer which was 31 hours and 45 minutes. I'm uncertain of another way to solve the problem. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I think the tag algebraic-topology should be removed

Comment: Use MathJax for typesetting. It is not possible to read the equation describing the evolution of $d(t)$ as currently posted.

Comment: The equation that you gave grows over time, are you sure that you have posted it correctly?

Answer (score -2):

d = 5*(2.7^.04t)              //(original equation)
2.5 = 5*(2.7^.04t)            //(set equation equal to 2.5)
0.5 = 2.7^.04t                //(divide by 5 on both sides)
log base 2.7 of 0.5 = 0.04t   //(log function)
t = 17.446241...              //(Answer)

You should probably talk to your teacher and ask her how he/she did the question.